# Also define the standard property 'animation-duration' for compatibility css

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-animations, web-deployment

```
.navbar-menu .menu li:hover > .submenu {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation-name: showSubMenu;            
    -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;
```

```
.navbar-mini-menu .mini-menu-options li:focus > .submenu {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation-name: showSubMenu; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;
             
  }
```

I tried below one, but submenus are still not visible (I am running this code on chrome with VS Code)

```
    .navbar-menu .menu li:hover > .submenu {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation-name: showSubMenu;
            animation-name: showSubMenu;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;
            animation-duration: .4s;
  }
```

Comment: -webkit- with animation is not needed since toooo long

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.